# AUCTeX: Format URLs with percent sign

Tags: hyperref, auctex

How I can bring AUCTeX not to format percent sign within `\url{}`?

[image]

The document will be set fine, but if some of such URLs are in a document, the source code does not look so good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AUCTeX comes with plenty of style files which add support for the corresponding LaTeX package.  For example, AUCTeX style `hyperref.el` includes additions catered by `hyperref.sty`.

AUCTeX [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Parsing-Files) says:

> #### 5.3 Automatic Parsing of TeX Files
>
> AUCTeX depends heavily on being able to extract information from the
>   buffers by parsing them. Since parsing the buffer can be somewhat
>   slow, the parsing is initially disabled. You are encouraged to enable
>   them by adding the following lines to your `.emacs` file.
>
> ```lisp
> (setq TeX-parse-self t) ; Enable parse on load.
> ```
>
> [...] Even when you have disabled the automatic parsing, you can force
>   the generation of style information by pressing <kbd>C-c C-n</kbd>.
>   This is often the best choice, as you will be able to decide when it
>   is necessary to reparse the file.